# Dynamic checkboxes issue

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, checkbox

Hi I have a JQuery problem with dynamic checkboxes and I don't know what I'm missing, if some one could help I appreciate here is my code

```
$('input[name="id_especieganado[]"]').each(function(e){
    //$('[name="id_especieganado[]"]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id_jurisdiccion = new Array();
        var jurisdicciones = "";
        //id_jurisdiccion = $("#id_jurisdiccion[]");
        var i = 0;
        $(this).bind('click',function(){
        //$('input[name="id_especieganado[]"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                id_jurisdiccion.push($(this).val());
                jurisdicciones += "id_jurisdiccion[]="+$(this).val()+"&";
                $("#buscarrfc").val("Hola");
            }
        })
        //if($("#id_jurisdiccion[]").attr("checked")==true)
            //alert($("input[name='id_jurisdiccion[]']").val());
        $.ajax({
            url:"funciones_jquery2.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: jurisdicciones,
            success: function(datos){
                $("#listamunicipios").html(datos);
                //alert(datos);
            }
        })
            //})
    });
```

The dynamic checkbox I write them from a database which is a Postgres DB and PHP

Here is the code embeded in a class

The checkboxes looks ok

```
private function especies_ganado()
    {
        $database = $this->conexion_db();
        $resultado = pg_query($database, "SELECT *FROM especies_ganado;");
        echo "<tr><td>";
        while($row = pg_fetch_array($resultado))
        {
            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"id_especieganado[]\" id=\"id_especieganado[]\" value=\"$row[id_especieganado]\"> $row[especie_ganado]<BR>";
        }
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
```

Comment: And what is the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `$.ajax()` call is in the `.each()` function body, so you are calling it for every checkbox (on page load), but I assume you want your data to be sent when the checkboxes are each clicked. Put them in the click handler.

Second, you have to collect every checkbox value in the click event handler, before sending the data.

```
// for every checkbox, add a click handler (no need for each anymore)
$('input[name="id_especieganado[]"]').bind('click',function() {
    // create an object for post data
    var post_data = {'id_jurisdiccion': new Array()};
    // collect the values from checked checkboxes
    $('input[name="id_especieganado[]"]:checked')).each(function() {
        post_data['id_jurisdiccion'].push($(this).val());
    });
    // send the data
    $.ajax({
        url:"funciones_jquery2.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: post_data,
        success: function(datos) {
            $("#listamunicipios").html(datos);
        }
    });
});
```